# ESLint, how to lint curly braces within JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm currently using react/jsx-curly-spacing to add spacing between curly braces within JSX. This works great for props but not for children within it.

For example,

```
<div>
    {this.renderSomething()}
</div>
```

Should become

```
<div>
    { this.renderSomething() }
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
"react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "always", {
  "allowMultiline": false,
  "spacing": {"objectLiterals": "always"}
}],
"object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"]
```

But neither of these have the desired outcome.

How do I achieve this using ESLint?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `"children": true,` to the setting to lint children of JSX elements:

```
"react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, "always", {
  "allowMultiline": false,
  "children": true,
  "spacing": {"objectLiterals": "always"}
}],
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed the children part of the docs! FWIW I ended up with ```"react/jsx-curly-spacing": [2, {"when": "always", "attributes": {"allowMultiline": false}, "children": true}]```